Spring Boot MVC on external tomcat. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: La cabecera del requerimiento es demasido grande
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:774)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseHeader(Http11InputBuffer.java:968)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseHeaders(Http11InputBuffer.java:593)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:285)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)

Which translates to something like "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Request header is too large"
Also, looking at tomcat's log, I see the next log repeating dozens of times:
TRACE 32104 --- [cursonline-gateway] [o-8080-exec-438] o.s.c.g.s.m.f.WeightCalculatorFilter     : Weights attr: {}
[cursonline-gateway] [o-8080-exec-438] .s.c.g.s.m.f.LoadBalancerFilterFunctions : LoadBalancerClientFilter url chosen: http://192.168.1.136:8080/cursonline-gateway/course

The URL should be /cursonline-course/course, not /cursonline-gateway/course, which corresponds to the Gateway server, not the microservice.
Looks like the gateways is resolving the URL the wrong way and calling itself infinitely until it breaks because of the header length. Or am I wrong?
What might be wrong in my configuration? I'm using Eureka Discovery server and my microservice as a client.
I'm not sure if the fail comes from the Gateway, the Eureka server, or the Eureka client configuration.
Running the applications (Gateway, Eureka and Microservice) from the embedded tomcat in Spring Tool Suite works fine, but not on an external Tomcat server
This is the routes configuration in the Gateway MVC server for the Microservice:
spring.cloud.gateway.mvc.routes[4].id=cursonline-user
spring.cloud.gateway.mvc.routes[4].uri=lb://CURSONLINE-USER
spring.cloud.gateway.mvc.routes[4].predicates[0]=Path=/user/**

I have tried to set the max request header size, to something like this:
server.max-http-request-header-size=10000000
But it doesn't do the trick and also I don't think is the correct solution, since it seems something is wrong in the configuration.

Edit: looks like specifying the 'server.port' property on the application.properties of the Microservice stops the "infinite loop", but it is still not working, since the Gateway redirects to himself but on the correct port...
Gateway is at port 8080.
Microservice is at port 8085.
It went from localhost:8080/cursonline-gateway/course,
to localhost:8085/cursonline-gateway/course
Which is still wrong, as it should be localhost:8085/cursonline-course/course
